# Checking up Intel assembly opcodes easily in Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, opcode

I have been looking for an practical tool that would print the opcodes of any Intel 64-bit or 32-bit instruction in Linux, eg. something like [`Hiew's`](http://www.hiew.ru/) assembler in DOS. A web-based service would be one option too.

As I wasn't able to find any, I made my own `bash` script, that creates an assembly source file from command line parameters (instruction[s] and <32/64>), compiles, links and disassembles it and shows the correct rows of disassembly. But is there already some program that would show *all* the possible encodings for any given instruction, eg. for `mov eax,ebx`? My approach using `nasm`, `ld` and `ndisasm` obviously only gives one possible encoding for each instruction.

With this script I can get the encodings used by `nasm` for 64 and 32-bit code, eg:

```
/home/user/code/asm$ showop 'nop;add eax,ebx;cpuid' 64

00000000  90                nop
00000001  01D8              add eax,ebx
00000003  0FA2              cpuid
```

But how could I get easily all the possible opcode encodings? Is there already some program available for that?

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage: showop instructions bits

asminstr=$1
bits=$2

# asminstr="nop;nop;nop;nop;add eax,ebx;nop;nop;nop"
# bits=64

numberofinstr=`echo $asminstr | grep -o ";" | wc -l`
((numberofinstr++))

if [ -f tempasmfile.asm ]
    then
    rm tempasmfile.asm
fi
if [ -f tempobjfile.o ]
    then
    rm tempobjfile.o
fi
if [ -f tempexefile ]
    then
    rm tempexefile
fi

printf "[bits $bits]\nsection .text\nglobal _start\n\n_start:\n`echo $asminstr | sed 's/;/\\n/g'`\n" >tempasmfile.asm

nasm -f elf$bits tempasmfile.asm -o tempobjfile.o
ld tempobjfile.o -o tempexefile

if [ $bits -eq 32 ]
then
    ndisasm -b $bits -e 0x60 tempexefile | head -n $numberofinstr
elif [ $bits -eq 64 ]
then
    ndisasm -b $bits -e 0x80 tempexefile | head -n $numberofinstr
fi
rm tempasmfile.asm
rm tempobjfile.o
rm tempexefile
```

Comment: Why do you need all possible opcodes? [x86asm.net](http://ref.x86asm.net/) provides an XML description of all the opcodes, maybe that will help?

Comment: For developing my own non-source debugger. I have x86asm.net's XML description and Intel's documentation too, but I'm looking for a practical tool that could be used to generate all different opcodes, preferably in Linux console.

Comment: Why do you need to generate all different ones? To test your own disassembler code? If so, how about generating random sequences (or not so random, sequential) and comparing the output of your disassembler with that of ndisasm? Obviously, there's no need to generate all possible values for `disp` and `imm`, but all prefixes, all opcodes (1-byte, 2-byte, etc), ModR/M and SIB values are doable. Note: AFAIR, there are AMD 3d!now instructions whose function is encoded in the `imm` operand, surprise.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Comparing disassemblies of random / non-random code produced by my own disassembler code and by `ndisasm` is a very good idea. I think I'll try that in developing the disassembler code.

Comment: You may want to pad the sequences with NOPs till the sequence is 29 bytes long. That should give the disassemblers enough input for an integral number of whole instructions (maybe a few more as I don't know what ndisasm does with unrecognized stuff, how much it skips).

Comment: If you like Hiew, check out [HT Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hte/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disassemblers, like [libdisasm](http://bastard.sourceforge.net/libdisasm.html) and [udis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) usually come with a lookup table for opcodes.

udis86 also comes with a command line tool (udcli), which you feed hex bytes and it gives you the decoded version.

Comment: I second the udis library.  It's easy to feed it single instructions.

Comment: I tried `udcli`, it's a very useful tool for disassembling a few bytes. And I think developing a debugger will a lot easier if I don't need to write the disassembler code for it myself, so in that sense using libdisasm, udis86 or both could be the most practical way to go. So I accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[radare2](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/) and the its fork [rizin](https://github.com/rizinorg/rizin) provide some cmdline tools exactly for that:

```
    $ rasm2 -a x86 nop
    90
    $ rasm2 -d -a x86 90
    nop
```

If using rizin, replace `rasm2` with `rz-asm`.

[source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-convert-hex-numbers-to-assemble-codes-4175441611/)

Another alternative is [`cstool`](https://github.com/aquynh/capstone/blob/master/cstool/README) from the `capstone-tool` package.