# Looking for program to show ASM instructions as binary ocodes

Tags: assembly, opcode

I am looking for a program (Linux/FOSS preferred) or a website that can **quickly and conveniently** show me the hex equivalents of (Intel) assembly instructions

E.g. I enter:

```
test al, al
```

and it outputs

```
84 c0
```

Writing inline assembly in C and checking what it compiles to does *not* cout as quick and convenient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476548/checking-up-intel-assembly-opcodes-easily-in-linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking up Intel assembly opcodes easily in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476548/checking-up-intel-assembly-opcodes-easily-in-linux)

Comment: The question is similar, but the answers here are better. The accepted answer over there only hints "usually come with a lookup table for opcodes" without evidence whether they actually can be easily queried in the assembling (not dis-assembling) direction, and the radare2 answer can only do single opcodes, as opposed to the `as` based answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use as from binutils for that. E.g:

```
$ echo -e "MOV DWORD PTR [RSP+4], 0x12345678" | as -o /dev/null -64 -al -msyntax=intel -mnaked-reg
GAS LISTING             page 1


   1 0000 C7442404  MOV DWORD PTR [RSP+4],0x12345678
   1      78563412 

$ echo -e "push eax" | as -o /dev/null -32 -al -msyntax=intel -mnaked-reg
GAS LISTING             page 1


   1 0000 50        push eax
```

Comment: Nice because `as` is usually available. The command line is a bit too long to remember it by heart, but it works well. Do you know if there is a static table in binutils or and API call that I could use to build a small web site for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use NASM in conjunction with NDISASM, e.g.:

This is the assembly file (named, say, `test.asm`) with your instruction:

```
bits 32
test al, al
```

You assemble it:

```
nasm -f bin test.asm -o test.bin
```

And then you disassemble it:

```
ndisasm -b 32 test.bin
```

And this is what you get:

```
00000000  84C0              test al,al
```

**Another way** is to produce the listing file when assembling:

```
nasm -f bin test.asm -o test.bin -l test.lst
```

And this is what you get in `test.lst`:

```
 1                                  bits 32
 2 00000000 84C0                    test al, al
```