# assembling nasm op codes at command line

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to figure out how I can use nasm to quickly get the hex for x86 operations.

I've tried things like

```
> echo "mov ax, 1" | nasm

> nasm < echo "mov ax, 1"
```

Neither work, but you get the idea of what I'm trying to do... Any ideas?

Comment: It wouldn't be really feasible. You need some context. `mov ax, 1` has the same opcode as `mov eax, 1` and `mov rax, 1` for different operating modes of the CPU.

Comment: Bah your totally right, that slipped my mind.. I tried  nasm <(echo "USE16 move ax,1") to no avail.. no errors but the output is empty

Comment: @ssg `nasm` will assume 16-bit code by default

Comment: But in general, I don't think it's possible to assemble `stdin`, since it requires backtracking, which you generally can't do on `stdin` (especially with `echo`ed text).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476548/checking-up-intel-assembly-opcodes-easily-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way, but this ought to work (you could make a script out of it):

```
echo "mov ax,1" > temp.asm && nasm -f bin -o temp.com temp.asm && ndisasm temp.com
```